# Returning hashmap objects instead of explicitly defined dto instances (bad practice?)

Tags: java, javascript, json, hashmap

I found out that since JSON doesn't make a difference between hashes and objects, I can bypass the "law" of always sticking to dto classes, and instead return an "on-the-fly" hashmap, or a list of hashmaps,  which will get JSON-serialized as a hash/es, and javascript later on will treat as a normal object/s.

Of course, this doesn't always apply, but there are those use cases where you cannot really guarantee the state of the data returned (what is there' what is not, some props might exist, others might not). This will cost me a number of abstractions to make in the "java" way. Plus, in the end, JavaScript won't even care what the original class of the returned objects was.

Is this a bad practice in general?

Answer (score 3):

Generally when serializing java objects to JSON its because you are making an AJAX call and receiving a a response. Typically for the javascript code to process that response it has to be in some type of consistent format a la `{user:{name:steve, favoritecolor:purple}}` etc. What using a java class to represent that instead of a vanilla hashmap gets you is consistency. You gaurantee to consumers of your JSON that they can rely on its contents because it will have the same fields as the DTO. Its the same reason you wouldn't forgo classes in a java program in favor of passing around a bunch of HashMaps.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem comes later when all your methods in your Java business code only accept HashMaps ;D
However if you have a small application only I would consider to define interfaces (instead fo classes) and generate at runtime with the proxy API classes that implement those interfaces but use a HashMap instead of writing a normal class.
See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html